# Readxl changes values with negative numbers

Tags: numbers, numeric, digits, readxl

I am quite new to data science and just started a project.
I have to convert Excel files to a dataframe I can use for this project. I would not like to do some VSB stuff to conver the Excel files but would love to do this in R.
I have 5 different types input files, 4 of them works great. One of them has negative numbers.

When I use the readxl function it changes numbers like: -6.75 to -6.7548000000000004 automaticly...
I've tried change the col_types or digits but maybe not in the right way.I would like to bring them back to 2 decimals

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably right.  Perhaps Excel is just displaying the values ​​rounded to two decimal places.  If you want to round the numbers after reading them in R, you can use `round()`:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Round

Comment: I edited my question a bit. I would like to bring them back to the original values of the 2 decimals